# Java web application performance

Tags: java

I have a question  regarding to Java web application performance.I develop a java web application using these frameWorks: struts , hibenrate , and spring but i notice bad performance when connection to database.Can any one give me Advices for Improves performance

Comment: How are you connecting to the database? What sort of technology?

Comment: i am using HibernateUtil class defining static final SessionFactory object in it and using static block to instantiate this object using Configuration(). Like  : sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

Comment: Not to falimiar with Hibernate. It sounds like you are not using connection pooling.

Comment: Is it possible to be patient with me and tell me how to use connection pool

Comment: I'm not familiar with these frameworks you have mentioned so I would not be the best to advise you on connection pooling within these frameworks. The idea behind a connection poolis the created connections are preserved in a pool. The preformance gained is that creating a connection is an expensive operation. So maintaining connections reduces the continual creation of connections.

Comment: Hibernate Connection Pool options: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-hibernatejdbc

Answer (score 2):

Try AppDynamics Lite, it takes 2 mins to install and will give you full database visibility of your database calls from your application.

http://appdynamics.com/products-free-download.php

I wrote this blog on Slow SQL and database latency, it should help you understand what may be causing your latency:
http://www.appdynamics.com/blog/2011/07/12/slow-sql-a-usual-suspect/

Answer (score 0):

You need visibility on what goes on in the database layer. P6spy is a jdbc-wrapper which logs this kind of information.

Comment: Plz can u tell me how to use P6spy

Comment: It appears the main site is down.  You might find http://blog.frankel.ch/tag/p6spy interesting, however.

Comment: i checked the log and found this log data which connecting to data base , check for foreign keys and load mapping files from hibernate

Comment: This is just a diagnostic. You need to find where the time goes.